# How to synchronize file changes with files on the FTP server?

Tags: ftp, sync, filezilla, winscp

My project files are in the local folder in **D:\xampp\htdocs\mysite**
The same files are on my FTP server.
A git repository would exist only locally in a .git directory to keep track.

I want to be able to edit my files locally, and the change to reflect on the server.

**Requirements**:

- Any new file on the server would be copied into the local dir
- Any change made to a local file will update the file on the server
- Ability to exclude some directories, files, extensions (for example .git)

What are the available softwares that can do this on windows? Does Filezilla do a better job maybe? or any other suggestions

I've tried WinSCP but i can't get it to work right. Whenever I make i change on one file, a dialog pops up (or console outputs  depending on where I've ran it) going through all the files and all the subdirectories. I don't know why is that since I've made change only to one file and synchronized all the files before trying to **keepuptodate**. It just spends time on some files which are already synchronized and up to date.

Comment: [Phpstorm Github integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/using-github-integration.html) would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the .cmd script I use to keep my local directory up to date with my remote one using WinSCP.

If you're seeing a whole lot of transfers when saving one file it's probably because you aren't excluding your .git folder. When you save a file git does a lot of changes to the .git folder. You're going to want to exclude it in the WinSCP profile.

```
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO Keeping Toolkit dir up to date...
@PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 > NUL
@START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" my-toolkit /keepuptodate c:\Users\a150495\toolkit /opt/ssp/apps/www/html/chris/toolkit /defaults "" -clean
```

Answer (score 0):

If WinSCP synchronizes file that were not changed, you probably have some issue with timezones or DST.

Refer to WinSCP FAQ for possible causes:
[Synchronization or keep remote directory up to date functions are not working. Why?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_synchronize)